# Parcel Data in Google

Tags: php, api, gis

I am creating a php script which grabs location (address and lat/lng) of a company and I'd like to get the Parcel Number so that I can display it in ArcGIS but I can't find any API's or large datasets for this info. Does anyone know of a source I can you to look up the parcel numbers in code?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know only about USA.  The County appraisal district may share that free, or share that with minimal fee like cost for DVD, and this is often ESRI shape file.  If all you need is parcel number, that should do.  Sometime local goverment (municipality)'s gis section redistribute this, so check that too.  Since it is shape file, if you now lat/lon, all you need is to find intersection of your coord with this parcel polygon layer, find one that match and read attribute.

obviously if the companies you are interested are all over the place in the USA (or even other countries), this approach becomes increasingly cumbersome...

*caveate*:

[ your question sounded like you are looking for API or "large data set" to tell parcel number, and i tried to answer that part.  but your tag says php so i am also wondering you already have data and all you need is to write php code to find intersection and pick parcel number, i actually dont know that answer to that Q....]

Comment: Yea, I was hoping google had an api to get the parcel number. since they have the parcel data in most US cities available on google maps. I guess it looks as though it will take some innovaiton. Thanks for the info though, I'll give you the check for this question unless someone else comes along with an API that exists out there.

Answer (score 1):

Google Earth uses [DataQuick](http://www.dataquick.com/) as a source for this data. Note that it isn't cheap — their listed price is on the order of tens of cents per lookup.

Comment: Thanks for the link, do you know why this information isn't freely available? as far as I know this is public data....but you have to get it from the county's office.